# Do sandcastles kill more people than sharks?

Tags: mortality, sharks

In 2007, [The Guardian made the following claim](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2007/jun/22/usa.travelnews):

> **Be afraid: sand castles can kill**
>
> The US bucket and spade brigade went on full alert yesterday after
> research by a top physician revealed that people falling into holes
> dug in the sand had accounted for more fatalities in the US since 1990
> than shark attacks - 16 as opposed to 12.
>
> The article, written by Dr Bradley Maron in the New England Journal of
> Medicine, said sand holes and tunnels, the byproduct of building sand
> castles and other juvenile beach fortifications, could turn into
> deathtraps with horrifying speed.

The "article" in question appears to actually only be a [letter to the editor](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMc070913).  Has there been any follow-up research to confirm that **sandcastles really do kill more people than sharks**?

Comment: why you use sandcastles instead of sandholes/tunnels in the title? yes those are the byproduct of making a sandcastle but they are totally different thing. is this a clickbait question? cause i feel like i just got baited hard.

Comment: @encryptoferia The title of the original Guardian article is "Be afraid: sand castles can kill", so blame them for the clickbait.  But obviously the point of this question is to verify the claim.

Comment: All I can offer is my own experience as a survivor of an almost death by asphyxiation by a collapsed sand tunnel at an early age, while I also have years of sea baths without one single interaction with a live shark

Comment: There are other sources of dangerous holes in sand...https://phys.org/news/2016-06-trees-mysterious-holes-huge-dunes.html

Comment: Given that the total number of deaths in the US at this period in this period as between 55M and 60M, the argument whether 12 or 16 are meaningfully different seems ridiculous. The correct scientific answer would be: the numbers are too small and the   data and definitions are too fuzzy to do meaningful statistics.

Comment: You may want to reword your title to read, *Do sandcastles kill more people than sharks **in the U.S.***?  Very few are killed by sand castles in Paraguay -- even fewer by sharks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Partial Answer: It's likely very close

Wikipedia provides a [list of fatal shark attacks in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fatal_shark_attacks_in_the_United_States) (reproduced below), but there is no such publicly available list for sand collapses so it's hard to compare. (The Guardian confuses the claim somewhat — it's about holes and tunnels in the sand, not sandcastles which are usually aboveground installations. One incident didn't even involve the kid playing in the sand — he was simply walking on the beach and fell in a hole.)

Maron, one of the authors of the letter to the editor, recommended that holes should be [no more than knee deep](https://www.csmonitor.com/The-Culture/Family/2012/0824/Student-dies-in-beach-sand-pit-Experts-warn-of-suffocation-danger) (not deep enough for falling sand to make it difficult for even small children to breathe) and filled back in before you leave so nobody trips into it. This is also [what a Virginia Beach master firefighter recommended](https://www.wtkr.com/news/virginia-beach-fire-rescue-dont-dig-deep-holes-at-the-beach-this-summer).

#### 21 US-based shark fatalities, 1990–2006

There were more shark fatalities than were reported by Wikipedia than the original source. I'm not sure why, but it's possible that these extra fatalities were just missed when searching.

| Name, Age | Date | Species |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Roy T. Tanaka | February 17, 1990 | Tiger shark |
| Suk Kyu (Steve) Park | November 19, 1991 | Tiger shark |
| Martha Joy Morrell, 41 | November 26, 1991 | Tiger shark |
| Bryan Adona, 29 | February 19, 1992 | Tiger shark |
| Aaron A. Romento, 18 | November 5, 1992 | Tiger shark |
| Daniel McMoyler | December 1993 | Tiger shark |
| Jim Broach | January 31, 1994 | Tiger shark |
| Michelle von Emster, 25 | April 16, 1994 | Great white shark |
| James Robinson, 42 | December 9, 1994 | Great white shark |
| William Covert, 25 | September 13, 1995 | Bull shark |
| James Willie Tellasmon, 9 | November 21, 1998 | Tiger shark |
| Nahid Davoodabai, 29 | March 18, 1999 | Unconfirmed, presumed to be a tiger shark |
| Thadeus Kubinski, 69 | August 30, 2000 | Bull shark |
| David Peltier, 10 | September 1, 2001 | Bull shark |
| Sergei Zaloukaev, 28 | September 3, 2001 | Tiger shark |
| Eric Reichardt, 42 | September 16, 2001 | Unconfirmed, possibly a bull shark or tiger shark |
| Deborah Blanche Franzman, 50 | August 19, 2003 | Great white shark |
| Courtney Marcher, 22 | April 4, 2004 | Unconfirmed, possibly a tiger shark |
| Willis R. McInnis, 57 | April 7, 2004 | Tiger shark |
| Randy Fry, 50 | August 15, 2004 | Great white shark |
| Jamie Marie Daigle, 14 | June 25, 2005 | Bull shark |

#### Sand Collapses

I tried to assemble my own list of sand collapse deaths between 1990–2006 in the US and I came up with 6 sources. There's certainly some I missed.

| Age | Date | What |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1992 | "A 7-foot-deep hole in beach sand collapsed on a 10-year-old boy who had helped dig it, and the boy died a day later, authorities said." ([Tampa Bay Times](https://www.tampabay.com/archive/1992/03/17/boy-dies-after-hole-collapses/)) |
| 12 | 1995 | "buried alive after the tunnel he was digging in the sand collapsed" in OC, MD ([Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/local/1995/06/30/wave-of-deaths-mayhem-troubles-ocean-city/3cf1ad4c-879c-4e22-8e96-b9758f834877/)) |
| 11 | 1997 | "died in an accident while digging a sand tunnel near the construction site of her family's new home near Fresno" ([Palo Alto Online](https://www.paloaltoonline.com/weekly/morgue/community_pulse/1997_May_21.OBITS21.html)) |
| 13 | August 2000 | A beach club in Salisbury, Mass: "digging a hole[...] died after the sand collapsed and buried him in a 5-foot-deep hole" ([Orlando Sentinal](https://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/os-xpm-2000-08-24-0008240108-story.html)) |
| 12 | July 2001 | Died in the hospital after digging into a sand dune at a beach in Marin County, California |
| 17 | May 2001 | On a RI beach, a teen fell headfirst into a hole and eventually died ([Courant](https://www.courant.com/news/connecticut/hc-xpm-2001-05-22-0105222605-story.html)) |

Notable mentions (it's hard to filter out non-matches):

- [Children Killed in Mine Accidents in the United States](https://usminedisasters.miningquiz.com/saxsewell/children.htm) (very old incidents)
- 3yo [girl dies in sand pit in UK](https://web.archive.org/web/20110217172045/https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-359289/Parents-warned-toddler-dies-sand-pit-tragedy.html), 2005
- 10yo [boy dies at Salmon Beach, CA](https://www.pressdemocrat.com/article/news/boys-ignored-warnings-before-sand-tunnel-collapse/), 2008
- 12yo [boy dies in sand dune in Utah](https://www.heraldextra.com/news/2008/sep/19/utah-boy-killed-in-sand-cave-collapse/), 2008
- 16yo [boy dies in Wales](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/wales/7550698.stm), 2008: "trapped 5ft (1.52m) underneath several tonnes of sand"
- 9yo [girl dies in Tulsa OK sandbox](https://www.fox23.com/news/breaking-news/sandbox-concerns-surface-after-child-dies/254314034/), 2011
- 12yo [boy dies in sand tunnel](https://www.nj.com/news/2012/07/12-year-old_boy_dies_today_aft.html) in NJ, 2012
- [3 sand hole deaths in 2014](https://www.cnn.com/2014/08/31/us/oregon-beach-collapse) in the US, including 2 adults
- 17yo [boy died in Florida](https://people.com/human-interest/oklahoma-teen-dies-after-sand-tunnel-collapses-in-florida/) after being pulled from his collapsed sand tunnel, 2016

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that sand tunnels and holes are distinct from sand castles. A very large sand castle might require the digging of a dangerous hole, but the headline is a little sensational by implying an innocent typical child’s sized sand castle is more dangerous than a shark.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Sure, but I'm not sure it's really "sensational". The stories I've found show that an innocent typical child sized hole or tunnel in the sand can kill someone (especially a child). I've seen holes like that on the beach and heard the news of someone dying in one on that same beach (not when I was there at least).

Comment: @Laurel are you seriously arguing that a typical child's sandcastle involves digging a 5-7 ft hole? Because that's what the headline is implying based on the data you've produced.

Comment: "sandcastles" can be a hyperbolic description of "sand constructions" (tunnels and holes) without invalidating the general point.

Comment: @Brondahl you don't need a typical sandcastle.  You might need a typical hole (or tunnel), and such a hole might be associated with a large sandcastle.  Separating up-type construction from down-type, which is likely to be adjacent, might be necessary to address the headline claim, but isn't going to be easy to extract from data.  And a 3ft-tall castle right next to a 3ft-deep hole seems both likely and a hazard for a small enough child.

Comment: @fectin yes ... that's *exactly* the point Todd and I are making ... that the headline is being sensationalist in describing these events as "sandcastles". ... because it's a hyperbolic description.

Comment: I'd dispute that digging even a 3 ft hole on a beach is a typical childhood activity, let alone 5-7ft.

Comment: Children often come with ambitious parents/other relatives (particularly fathers).  I've seen 3-foot (1 m) holes near sandcastles many times.  I haven't seen too many 5-7 ft holes though.  You get the right beach (sand consistency), an ebbing tide and some Type-A dads and suddenly insane castle construction pops up everywhere.  I've also seen people burying people in the sand (so that just the head is showing).  I've been involved in an "Oh $hit, the tide's coming in" rescue attempt once

Comment: Also, I'm sure some larger sandcastle builds are made from sand from multiple, smaller holes, so it wouldn't even be a 1:1 correlation of large sandcastles to large holes. Four 4x4x2 holes would provide marginally more sand than one 5x5x5 hole, while being easier to actually get sand from (once you get more than 2-3 feet down, getting the dug-up sand back out of the hole becomes more difficult).

Comment: @DoktorJ it depends where the damp sand starts, because damp is stickier and better for making sandcastles. If you're a long way up the beach, it's easier to go down vertically than to fetch water/damp sand from the tide line.

Comment: Huh. I realize with small sample sizes you're going to get outliers, but it's odd to me that the number of fatalities from great white attacks is the same as that of bull sharks (4 vs. 4 in your list, though bull sharks might be 5 for the one where they weren't sure); my understanding was that bull sharks were generally the more dangerous species, not because they're physically more dangerous (they're half the size), but because they're more aggressive and they tend to travel close to shorelines, and even up rivers, where great whites typically stick to deep water away from the shore.

Comment: @Flydog57 rescue **attempt**?

Comment: @ShadowRanger there are probably far more bull shark attacks, but if they are rarely fatal where great white attacks are mostly fatal that covers the discrepancy. And from what I understand from my (admittedly limited) reading that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: @Brondahl While I don't mean to invalidate your point at all, I should note that in my experience, children love deep holes, and some children love trying to dig them. I've never seen them do it at a beach, though (that tends to require a serious spade, which is usually absent at a beach).